# Axis rotation with an oriented bounding box

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, rotation, bounding-box

I'm trying to put an oriented bounding box around the stamford rabbit for a project. To do this, I create a covariance matrix with the vertices and use the eigenvector columns as the new axis vectors for the OBB.

To draw the OBB, I take the cross product of the vector columns with the x,y and z axes to find the vector perpendicular both, then I use the dot product to find the angle between them.

```
//rv,uv,fv are the normalised column vectors from the eigenvector matrix.
// Calculate cross product for normal
crossv1x[0] = xaxis[1]*rv[2] - xaxis[2]*rv[1];
crossv1x[1] = xaxis[2]*rv[0] - xaxis[0]*rv[2];
crossv1x[2] = xaxis[0]*rv[1] - xaxis[1]*rv[0];

// Calculate cross product for normal
crossv2y[0] = yaxis[1]*uv[2] - yaxis[2]*uv[1];
crossv2y[1] = yaxis[2]*uv[0] - yaxis[0]*uv[2];
crossv2y[2] = yaxis[0]*uv[1] - yaxis[1]*uv[0];

// Calculate cross product for normal
crossv3z[0] = zaxis[1]*fv[2] - zaxis[2]*fv[1];
crossv3z[1] = zaxis[2]*fv[0] - zaxis[0]*fv[2];
crossv3z[2] = zaxis[0]*fv[1] - zaxis[1]*fv[0];

//dot product:
thetaX = dot(xaxis,rv,1)*180/PI;
thetaY = dot(yaxis,uv,1)*180/PI;
thetaZ = dot(zaxis,fv,1)*180/PI;
```

I then apply a rotation around the cross product vector with an angle determined by the dot product (glRotatef(angle,cross[0],cross[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQxps.png),cross[2]) for each axis). I then draw an axis aligned bounding box, then to the inverse rotation back to the original position.

```
        glRotatef(thetaY,crossv2y[0],crossv2y[1],crossv2y[2]);
        glRotatef(thetaZ,crossv3z[0],crossv3z[1],crossv3z[2]);
        glRotatef(thetaX,crossv1x[0],crossv1x[1],crossv1x[2]);

        glTranslatef(-meanX, -meanY, -meanZ);
        glColor3f(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
        AOBB(1); //Creates an axis aligned box.

        glRotatef(-thetaX,crossv1x[0],crossv1x[1],crossv1x[2]);
        glRotatef(-thetaZ,crossv3z[0],crossv3z[1],crossv3z[2]);
        glRotatef(-thetaY,crossv2y[0],crossv2y[1],crossv2y[2]);
```

As you can see below, the box does not fit exactly onto the rabbit, nor does it align with the axis I have drawn... Am I missing something here? Ive fried my brain trying to find the solution but to no avail...

[image]

Comment: As a sidenote: Unless the mean of the bunny is exactly in the origin, the new "local coordinate system" or eigenvector system is **not** centered at (0,0,0) but at (meanX,meanY,meanZ)

Comment: Also note: the mid point `[(max-min)/2]` is **not** the mean point `[sum(x)/nx]`!

Answer (score 2):

> To draw the OBB, I take the cross product of the vector columns with the x,y and z axes to find the vector perpendicular both, then I use the dot product to find the angle between them.

Those "vector columns?" Those are actually the columns of the *rotation matrix* you want to generate.

So instead of using these vectors to compute rotation angles, just build a matrix with those (normalized) vectors as the columns. Upload it with `glMultMatrix`, and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks! that got it aligning with the axis perfectly, but the box is still not fully around the bunny. I think this is because the rotations have moved the centre point away from 0,0,0. I tried putting a translation either side of the rotation matrices with a magnitude of the mid point between max/min of each axis (e.g. xc = (xmax+xmin)/2) to counter this like so: 

            glMultMatrixd(M);
            glTranslatef(-xc, -yc, -zc); 
            glColor3f(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
            AOBB(1);
            glMultMatrixd(Mb);
            glTranslatef(xc, yc, zc);

But it seems slightly off..